# Why can't I reference net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext from JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports

I grabbed an old JSF (in Netbeans) project that I needed to update.  I noticed that the libraries were missing, so I went and snagged the current version of JasperReports (.jar) and all the commons/other support .jars necessary.  Ultimately, when I try to run the project it fails at the JasperSoft `JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream)` call with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException.getMessage(JRRuntimeException.java:146)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException.getMessage(JRRuntimeException.java:138)
at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2982)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:695)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:709)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:709)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:667)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:721)
at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.uniformLogFormat(UniformLogFormatter.java:448)
at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.format(UniformLogFormatter.java:178)
at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:211)
at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:116)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:875)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Other possibly related oddities:  While the project clean/builds into a .war fine (no errors), running it in Netbeans gives a popup about "One or more projects were compiled with errors." and lets me run anyways.  I see no errors in the console/logs though.  I have found a couple of CSS files (inside JasperReports) that are being flagged as being in error (the "background:" tag specifically), but why would Netbeans even try to parse CSS?  If I pull out support files (such as commons-digester) then it blows up at the same location (the call to JasperSoft), but with no class found for digester.  So, we DO seem to be getting into JasperSoft despite the text of the error I'm getting...  Any ideas on how to resolve this class that can't be found even though JasperSoft itself is clearly *starting* to run before hitting the error?

Comment: Where's the root cause?

Comment: Wait .. that code threw that exception during `e.printStackTrace()` call of a caught `JRRuntimeException`? Ugh, awkward.

Comment: Perhaps I can dig around and find an older version of Jasper Reports somewhere and try backdating to it to see what happens.

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint there and see what the `e` really was (type, message), at least without logging/printing the stack trace. It may already represent the whole answer at its own.

Comment: Wow.  I can't get the contents of e.  The call that causes the fault is wrapped in a try/catch, but is breaking so hard that the contents of that block never even gets called.  It's as if it shuts down immediately, and I don't know what's giving me the stack trace.

Comment: Is that `inputStream` `null` or not?

Comment: Not null.  I think I may be on to something though.  The libraries don't seem to be loading properly...  Trying to work through that, getting some different funky errors (but in Jasper dependencies now instead of Jasper)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JasperSoft and support libraries cannot be copied into source as class files (unlike what is commonly done with other support libraries in desktop applications for JWS), they must be referenced as true libraries.

Comment: so, if I have war with servlet which calls jar with reports, should i add jasper libs to war file?